# find if a pasted content is html or plain text using jQuery

Tags: jquery, copy-paste

I am trying to clean the pasted content before I add it to my text area. so I use a call back, but if I use plain text then the content is not calling in the call back, only html text is getting called in the function.
Is there a way to find if the content pasted into the text area is html content or plain content?
When a content is pasted in my text area I am using this

```
var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/html');
```

but the above code holds good for html.
but I need to know if the content is a html or plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sPlain = 'plain text'
        , sHtml = 'text <i>with tags</i>'
        , wrapped_sp = `<div>${sPlain}</div>`
        , wrapped_sh = `<div>${sHtml}</div>`
        , w2t_sp = $(wrapped_sp).text()
        , w2t_sh = $(wrapped_sh).text()
        , isplain_sp = ( w2t_sp == sPlain )
        , isplain_sh = ( w2t_sh == sHtml ) 

    console.log( "%s is %stext/plain", sPlain, isplain_sp ? "" : "NOT " );
    console.log( "%s is %stext/plain",  sHtml, isplain_sh ? "" : "NOT " );
```

As answer to the original question specifically:

```
let is_bufferText_plain = ( $(`<div>${bufferText}</div>`).text() == bufferText );
if( is_bufferText_plain ){
  // do whatever is required if the bufferText content is text/plain
}else{
  // do whatever is required if the bufferText content is text/html
}
```

Comment: my content is received from the clipboard, so before I paste it I need to know if the content pasted is html or plain text,
this is where I receive the content 

var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/html');

so how do I find before I proceed to paste on my text area,

Comment: Just use jQuery's [text method](https://api.jquery.com/text/) - it does what you want.